# Grid as Drop target developing UI using SWT in RCP application

Tags: drag-and-drop, grid, swt, cell, droptarget

Developing a UI for a RCP application using SWT? I wanna make grid as a drop target.  When text is dropped on the grid(cell) content of the cell must change.  I made my grid as target but could not get the cell coordinates?  How do I get control of the grid cell?  I have recently started learning about the DND.  Please let me know any good reading material to learn about DND.  Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if you need any additional details.

Comment: What do you mean by "grid", what control/widget are you using? Is it a Table, or Tree?

Comment: Its a user defined widget.  Similar to Table but has view like a matrix.  It uses GridLayout.

Comment: Then it really depends on how that grid is implemented, to answer your question. If it is a canvas with overlayed drawing to represent the grid, then you need to add drop target listeners to that Composite. But if there are controls/widgets added to it to represent cells then drop target listeners might be required on all those controls too. As i said it depends on the implementation of the custom control. You should start by looking at some tutorial on how to add drag and drop support in SWT and then look to adding that support to your custom control.